# Calling webservice from C++

Tags: c++, web-services

Is there a way to call a webservice from C++ code (gcc - not MS)?

Comment: Related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450488/a-good-c-library-for-soap
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086/c-and-soap
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166/c-web-service-framework

Answer (score 6):

[gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) is excellent :)

(Dont be fooled by the crappy looking website)

Answer (score 1):

[POCO Remoting](http://www.appinf.com/en/products/remoting.html) is a commercial solution based on the open source [POCO C++ Libraries](http://pocoproject.org/).

**Edit** You might want to try [Qt SOAP](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsoap) it is dual licensed commercial / LGPL.

Comment: The link to Qt SOAP doesn't exist anymore :(